# How do I pass a variable to Linest for the last row number?

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm trying to do is pass the variable row (which is the last line in a dynamic array) to the Linest function to perform a regression analysis.

```
=LINEST(R[5]C[-7]:R[row]C[-7],R[5]C[1]:R[row]C[8])
```

Excel gives me `Runtime error 1004` when it runs the above statement. It works fine if I don't use the variable row but an actual number.

Comment: Is this VBA or a regular Excel function?  If it's VBA, how are you calling the worksheet function `LINEST`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing the error is because your variable isn't being recognized as such. Try this:

```
"=LINEST(R[5]C[-7]:R[" & row & "]C[-7],R[5]C[1]:R[" & row & "]C[8])"
```

Also, `Row` is a member of the `Range` object, so I'd recommend changing your variable name to something else (e.g. `lRow`, `iRow`, etc.) to avoid possible confusion.